# VP8 Encoding Nexus 5 returns empty/0-Frames

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-mediacodec, vp8, nexus-5

I'm trying to encode my camera feed to VP8. The problem is: when I get the frame from the output buffer, the byte array is always different size but all entries are 0.

Here's the code where I grab the frame and print it:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        encoderIndex = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(encoderOutputInfo, timeOut);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (encoderIndex) {
    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
        // something
        break;
    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
        // something else
        break;
    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
        // something completely different
        break;
    default:
        // get encoded frame
        byte[] frame = new byte[encoderOutputInfo.size];

        mEncoderOutputBuffers[encoderIndex].get(frame);

        Log.v(tag, "got frame. size: " + frame.length);
        Log.v(tag, "printing frame");
        Log.v(tag, printBytesAsBinary(frame));

        mEncoderOutputBuffers[encoderIndex].clear();

        // release encoder output buffer
        mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderIndex, false);
}
```

And the Logcat print:

```
02-07 11:48:19.014: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): got frame. size: 427
02-07 11:48:19.014: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): printing frame
02-07 11:48:19.014: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
02-07 11:48:20.544: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): got frame. size: 379
02-07 11:48:20.544: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): printing frame
02-07 11:48:20.544: V/GoogleEncoder(24883): 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Anyone had this problem already and can tell me what I might be doing wrong? I already tried messing with the output buffer (e.g. rewind()) but nothing seems to work.

Oddly enough, encoding works on devices with Cyanogenmod 11 which is also 4.4 (Tried on a S3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaCodec` doesn't put the `ByteBuffer` in the correct position.  You need to position it manually after the call to `dequeueOutputBuffer()`:

```
int encoderStatus = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_USEC);
...
ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
encodedData.position(info.offset);
encodedData.limit(info.offset + info.size);
```

(See [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest).)  That's not the same as `rewind()`, though I'm a little surprised that didn't work -- I would have expected that output would usually start at the beginning of the buffer.

There are some known issues with [VP8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58834) on Android 4.3, though you don't seem to be hitting those.

If this does not fix your issue, it would be helpful to know the device you're using (S3 for both Android and Cyanogen?), the Android software version, to see the code you're using to `configure()` the `MediaCodec`, and what values are used.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Manually setting offset and limit of the buffer fixed the problem. It's working now on a 4.4.2 Nexus 5. Encoding also works on a CM11 S3 and S1, but not decoding. Strangely, my Galaxy Nexus that has CM11 can encode AND decode.